Source feature class is missing while creating Network Dataset from Feature dataset in ArcGIS Pro
I followed the following procedure to create Network dataset.

Create a feature dataset "Road" with a feature class "Roads"



Create Network Dataset from "Road" Feature Dataset



However,  no Source Feature Class was populated to select


How do I fix it?

Hi I'm see you're working in an esri product (ArcMap / ArcGIS online) ? You should include that in the question and especially in the question tags (like 'ArcMap' / 'ArcGIS online') you'll get more (+relevant) feedback that way.

Thank you. I have edited my question.

Are there actually any feature classes in your feature dataset?  You screenshot shows a "Roads" feature class that is NOT within your "Road" feature dataset.  Click the disclosure triangle next to the dataset to show what feature classes are within it (and replace your screenshot in the question so that we can see).

Thank you for your highlight. Yes "Roads" feature class is not under "Road" feature dataset. After I moved "Roads" under "Road", I could create the network dataset.
